# Automating DOORS Module Export with Python

Tags: python, automation, ibm-doors

Has anyone tried to automate DOORS module export with Python? Within DOORS there is an option within the module to export it as a csv, and I'm sure it can be done with DXL; however, I am trying to do it automatically with Python.

Any help would be awesome, thanks in advance!

Comment: DOORS only "understands" DXL, but one could write a wrapper which eases communication originating from other languages. Domoran started the project https://github.com/domoran/DriveDOORS some time ago, but it looks like this has not been finished. Maybe you have the time to work with him to complete the work. Other, commercial, solutions, like "MDWorkbench for DOORS" by SodiusWillert focus more on java as far as I know. Also, usage of DOORS' OSLC API might be possible for you.

Comment: I have recently developed a simple python tool for exporting DOORS modules. It basically runs a DXL script which exports modules specified in a configuration file - data from the config file is used for dynamic generation of variables in the DXL script. Probably not what you are looking for, but it might give you some inspiration: https://github.com/ytaa/doors_exporter